# Storing FileURLs

Tags: image, qt, qml, qtquick2

I have an application that allows the user to load and display images. In the QML front end I am using a fileDialog to get the file URLs which are then loaded using an image loader in C++.

The issue I have at the moment is that if you want to load multiple images you have to load them all at once because once the fileURLs changes, the old URLs are lost.

What is the best way to go about storing the URLs so that I can keep the images displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution 1:
C++ side, Use a `QStringList` or a `QVector` to store paths  and load Images from it. Qml side, each time you get new URL push it back to your `QStringList`.

solution 2: 
Declare a qml array (`property var array:[]`) and store in it the new urls, load images from this list.